# Как передать cookie на все страницы сайта?

Tags: php, cookie

Ребят, подскажите, как мне установить cookie для всех страниц сайта то есть иметь к ним доступ с любой страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для параметра **path** установить значение **"/"**. [Подробнее тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: @Deonis и я смогу получить к этим cookie с любой страницы?

Comment: @igolka97, Я же вам даже ссылку на мануал дал. Цитата:

>If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain.

    setcookie("MyCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "site.ru");

Comment: @Deonis да это то  я понял. Но смогу ли я получить их обычным $_COOKIE[''] с любой страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Куки устанавливаются на клиенте с привязкой к адресу вебсайта. Ты сможешь получить к ним доступ с любой страницы